# Improvements to Recently Viewed Component in React

Tags: reactjs, sorting, filter, state

I have this small app I created using a REST Countries API.

https://rest-country-react.netlify.app/

If you click on one country card then it is displayed under the "Recently Viewed" header. So far it works fine, but I wanna tune it a little bit. What I thought I'd do:

#1 Add a limit of three recently viewed countries, so basically if the user clicks on 4,5,6 countries, only the three most recent clicked countries are displayed.

#2 Visited countries are currently sorted in an "oldest" to "newest" order. I wanna reverse that so the newest gets the first spot, then the second newest, then the third and so on.

I am stuck because I am not sure how to implement these tweaks. For the first one I thought I'd filter the state array before mapping it in the component, saying something like... if index > 2, filter it out the element.

But for the second, I haven't found a solution yet. Maybe instead of using concat() method, I should use unshift()? From what I read in the React documentation, it's not advised to directly edit the state or its array, so I don't know what to do.

```
  onCountryClick(country) {
    const uniqueRecent = [
      ...new Set(this.state.recentlyViewed.concat(country)),
    ];
    this.setState({
      // ... other state updates here
      recentlyViewed: uniqueRecent
    });
  }
```

Comment: It would be great if you share the code of that component to make future answers more accurate.

Comment: Yep, edited main post.

Comment: Got it, please check the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually multiple solutions, but let's take the one which is very clean and understandable:

```
onCountryClick(country) {
  const { recentlyViewed } = this.state;
  const newState = {}; // add your other updates here

  if (!recentlyViewed.includes(country)) {
    // firstly take first two items as a new array
    newState.recentlyViewed = recentlyViewed.slice(1);
    // add country into beginning of new array
    newState.recentlyViewed.unshift(country);
  }

  this.setState(newState);
}
```

Firstly we check if country already exists in the `recentlyViewed` array and if no - then continue.
We must use new array when updating the state, so simply calling `unshift()` method will not work for us as it modifies original array and doesn't return new one. Instead, we firstly call [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method which solves two main things for us: it takes a portion of original array (in our case items with index 0 and 1) and return new array with them. Great! Now we can easily use `unshift` to add country into beginning of new array. Then simply update the state.

With this solution you always get a new array with max of 3 countries, where the first item is the newest.